# Directive loading ng-transclude content before directive template loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm making a directive that has a template that loads in, with some transcluded content that gets passed in. So essentially my html is

```
<my-directive>
    <div>Some transcluded content</div>
</my-directive>
```

However, when my page loads, for a split second I see just the transcluded content on the page. I'm guessing there's a delay between when the page initially loads and when the directive template loads. Is there a way to hide the transcluded content until the directive template has loaded?

Thank you so much, it's really a jarring experience having that load first quickly. Does anyone know a way how to fix this?

Comment: Look at [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 1):

Well, ok so I've found a solution that works using `ngCloak`. I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), adding this css

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and the `ng-cloak` directive to my directive

```
<my-directive id="..." class="..." ng-cloak>
    <div>Transcluded content</div>
</my-directive>
```

This prevents the div from displaying until the directive has been compiled/evaluated. Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `ng-hide` to your directive temporary and it will be removed automatically as soon as angular comes in action.

```
<my-directive ng-show="true" class="ng-hide">
    <div>Some transcluded content</div>
</my-directive>
```

And define `.ng-hide { display: none }` to your CSS file or else you can write something like this:

```
<my-directive>
    <div ng-bind="Some transcluded content"></div>
</my-directive>
```

Hope This helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: How does angular automatically remove the ng-hide class? I just tried this and it's not removed automatically.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I've just updated the answer. Please have a look. You  have to add `ng-show` attribute also.